# Difference between fetch().stream().findFirst() vs fetchAnyInto

Tags: jooq

Can someone let me know what is the difference between the below queries? If both are same which one should be preferred over the other?

**Query 1**

```
dslContext
        .selectFrom(AIR_TRANSACTION)
        .where(
            AIR_TRANSACTION
                .TICKET_NUMBER
                .eq(ticketNumber)
                .and(AIR_TRANSACTION.SPOTNANA_PNR_ID.eq(pnrId)))
        .orderBy(AIR_TRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_DATE.desc())
        .fetch()
        .stream()
        .findFirst()
        .map(r -> r.into(AirTransaction.class));
```

**Query 2**

```
Optional.ofNullable(
        dslContext
            .selectFrom(AIR_TRANSACTION)
            .where(
                AIR_TRANSACTION
                    .TICKET_NUMBER
                    .eq(ticketNumber)
                    .and(AIR_TRANSACTION.SPOTNANA_PNR_ID.eq(pnrId)))
            .orderBy(AIR_TRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_DATE.desc())
            .fetchAnyInto(AirTransaction.class));

JOOQ Version - 3.17.7
Postgres Version - 14.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are the same, logically, but not necessarily from a performance perspective. Think about what each operation does:

### Query 1

- `.fetch()` fetches all data from the JDBC `ResultSet` into memory as a `Result<AirTransactionRecord>` (this includes going through the `ExecuteListener::recordStart` lifecycle for every record!)
- `.stream()` is lazy, implemented by `ArrayList::stream` and doesn't do anything on its own
- `.findFirst()` is a terminal operation on the stream that discards all elements after the first
- `.map()` maps 0..1 `AirTransactionRecord` into the `AirTransaction` POJO

### Query 2

- `fetchAnyInto()` fetches only 0..1 elements from the JDBC `ResultSet` into memory as `AirTransactionRecord`, then, maps it into the `AirTransaction` POJO. (this only includes going through the `ExecuteListener::recordStart` lifecycle for that single record)
- In the future, the intermediate `AirTransactionRecord` might even be skipped, as it might not be necessary, see [#6737](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6737)

### The difference

The difference only manifests when there are more than 1 records in the `ResultSet`, in case of which Query 2 is much faster than Query 1. This is unlikely what you want, so in such a case, it would be a good idea to add a `limit(1)` clause to prevent more than 1 records to be sent from SQL.

Other than that, the two approaches are effectively equivalent.

### Alternative

There's also `.fetchOptionalInto(AirTransaction.class)`, which you could call, to skip having to manually wrap things in an optional. The semantics of that is slightly different in case the query produces multiple records, though, as it may throw a `TooManyRowsException`

Comment: `This is unlikely what you want, so in such a case, it would be a good idea to add a limit(1) clause to prevent more than 1 records to be sent from SQL.` This statement I did not understand properly. Are you suggesting that I should also add `limit(1)` to Query 2? If yes why? Is it to prevent database driver from loading too many results in memory?

Comment: @tuk: Your explicit usage of `fetchAny()` as opposed to `fetchOne()` or `fetchOptional()` hints at there possibly being more than 1 rows, in case of which you just want the first. If there can be more than one row, then yes indeed, you *should* tell the RDBMS that you're going to fetch only the first using a `LIMIT 1` clause. I'll blog about this, soon. It's a commonly overlooked thing.

Comment: One more clarification in Query1 `recordStart()` from `ExecuteListener` will be called for each result present in `ResultSet` and in Query2 it will be called only once. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @tuk: Yeah, I'll add that to the answer